# Automate The boring Stuff - chapter 11 - Filling out and submitting forms p. 259

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run the code to log into gmail.com but the login process seems to have changed. I have modified the code as follow but keep getting the following error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
Dose anyone see or know what I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://gmail.com')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys('some_email@gmail.com')
nextElem = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextElem.click()                # click the button
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
passwordElem.send_keys('password')
passwordElem.submit()
```

Comment: A stable Gmail API for Python: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *[wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the presence of element* with `id="Passwd"`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
passwordElem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
passwordElem.send_keys('password')
passwordElem.submit()
```

Comment: With the following modification to my code, it works. Thanks alecxe.          wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)